# Query string getting changed

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, query-string, umbraco

We use a third party service which returns a URL in an email like:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/retrieve-quote.aspx?cid=tela04NrLRCEB4YSJaHNnrmMgfzhKGWDQMNWU9gA4LoIZ4xkAdjDj9NQxK9NokSj&pid=hzRtwgPKiGFXnqVI78upf3QmpexmqtkJ0sYPtE0Tam8%3d
```

When you click on the link and it takes you to the page on the website (built on Umbraco 4.9), the URL in the address bar is now:

```
https://www.domain.co.uk/retrieve-quote.aspx?cid=tela04nrlrceb4ysjahnnrmmgfzhkgwdqmnwu9ga4loiz4xkadjdj9nqxk9noksj&pid=hzrtwgpkigfxnqvi78upf3qmpexmqtkj0sypte0tam8=
```

I'm not sure is this is an Umbraco issue, or an IIS issue, but the query string is now lowercase and the last 3 digits have been changed.

The only rewrites we have are directory URL's are set to true in the config, and we are redirecting some old URL's to new one's, but this URL has stayed the same.

Answer (score 2):

The querystring is being changed because it is url encoded, the %3d at the end of the first URL is the code for the equals sign

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: just to check, why was the other equal sign in the string not encoded? `id=hz`

Comment: Thanks Keith, that's pointed me nearer to an answer. The %3d changing to = is not the problem, more that Umbraco is changing the query string into lowercase which is causing the problem. If the query string is in the correct format having = on the end still works. Now to find out how to prevent Umbraco putting it into lowercase !!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found the problem which was some 3rd party URL rewriting code that was installed after Umbraco. This was changing all URL's to lowercase and not Umbraco. We've since got the 3rd party to change their code and all is ok now.